# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'send' - Discord,py Bot error

Tags: discord, discord.py, attributeerror

```
channel = client.get_channel
    if message.content.lower().startswith('experiment'): 
        moji = await client.get_channel.send("https://c.tenor.com/R_itimARcLAAAAAd/talking-ben-yes.gif")
        emoji = [":blue_circle:"]
        for experiment in emoji:
            await client.add_reaction(emoji)
```

What I want the bot to do is when the user types 'experiment' the bot will send the link to the photo and it will attach the emoji to it. It gives me this error.

Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\13129\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "c:\Users\13129\Desktop\Python Bot\Ben.py", line 50, in on_message
moji = await client.get_channel.send("https://c.tenor.com/R_itimARcLAAAAAd/talking-ben-yes.gif")
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'send'

I tried changing a few things on line 20 but nothing seems to be working!

Answer (score 1):

`Bot.get_channel` is a method which takes a `channel_id` as a positional argument and gets you a `Union[StageChannel, VoiceChannel, CategoryChannel, TextChannel, Thread (if you are on master)]` if the ID you pass to it matches one it has in its internal cache (this requeires `members` intent)

you can't do
`get_channel.send()`, `get_channel` is a `method`, or in other words, a bound function to `Bot` class.

here is an example usage:

```py
channel = bot.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
await channel.send("hello there!")
```

also,

`client.add_reaction(emoji)` is not a thing

`Message.add_reaction` is. `await channel.send()` returns a `Message` object which you can store in a variable and then add your emoji

```py
message = await channel.send("hello there!")
for emo in emoji:
    await message.add_reaction(emo)
```

and I am pretty sure that you need the `unicode` of that emoji and the string would raise `UnknownEmoji` error, but if it doesn't then it's fine. If it does though, just use `"\N{Large Blue Circle}"` instead `:blue_circle:` and that should fix it.

Comment: The top part worked but it's not adding the reaction. Its giving this error: 
 ```File "C:\Users\13129\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\message.py", line 69, in convert_emoji_reaction      
    raise InvalidArgument('emoji argument must be str, Emoji, or Reaction not {.__class__.__name__}.'.format(emoji))
discord.errors.InvalidArgument: emoji argument must be str, Emoji, or Reaction not list.```

Comment: `message.add_reaction(experiment)` instead of `message.add_reaction(emoji)` in your code

Comment: @Rose It kinda worked. It did add the reaction to the users response but I want it to add to the bots response. Now when the user types "experiment" it adds the circle there but the bot posts the picture. Is there a way I can get it to add a reaction to the bots response?

Comment: you have to do `mess = await channel.send("your bot's message")` and then `await mess.add_reaction(experiment)` in the for loop instead of `message.add_reaction` if you have a use-case for it later

Comment: Its telling me ```Channel is not defined``` in ```mess =  await channel.send("")``` Is it possible for me to have it automatically know what channel its in?

Comment: you need to define channel. This is the variable that you are storing with `channel 
= bot.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)`, and then `mess=await channel.send("your link")` and then `mess.add_reaction(experiment)`

Comment: Now its telling me this: 
```File "c:\Users\13129\Desktop\Python Bot\Ben.py", line 51, in on_message
    moji = await channel.send("https://c.tenor.com/R_itimARcLAAAAAd/talking-ben-yes.gif")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'```

Comment: I also added this: 
```channel  = client.get_channel("CHANNEL_ID")```

Comment: it's not "CHANNEL_ID", it's CHANNEL_ID, you need to input the integer as it is, not make it a string

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing client.get_channel() with something in the brackets like a channel ID, not `client.get_channel` If not how will they know what channel to send it to.

For **Prefixed Commands**

```py
@client.command()
async def command_name(ctx)
    await ctx.send()
    # Sends to what ever channel the command was sent in
```

Comment: How would I get the bot to send the link then? Also this is a bot used and different discords so there can't be one specific channel ID. Can you possibly send the message as how it would look in the code?

Comment: What type of command are you using, slash or prefixed

Comment: this is `on_message` @FishballNooodles

Comment: When the user sends "experiment" the bot will send the photo and attach the reaction to it. Is it not possible to do this with ```on_message```?

Comment: If using on_message, Do await message.channel.send(). Remove all the await client.get_channel

Comment: It now sends the message but when it adds the reaction it gives this error:

Comment: ``` File "c:\Users\13129\Desktop\Python Bot\Ben.py", line 54, in on_message
    await client.add_reaction(emoji)
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'add_reaction'```